# HTML-CSS DIV Element Not Starting From Bottom of Container

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have each bar begin from the bottom but they begin from the top of the container. How can I align them at the bottom of the container. I tried `vertical-align: bottom

```css
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: grey;
  height: calc(100% - 65%);
  top: 10%;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar-phase-label{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar.a{
  background-color: #BA55D3;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 25%;
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar.b{
  background-color: #FF8C00;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 40%;
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar.c{
  background-color: #81C784;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="phase-balancing-bar-graph-container">
  <div class="graph-wrapper">
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar-phase-label">A</div>
      <div class="bar a"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar-phase-label">B</div>
      <div class="bar b"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar-phase-label">C</div>
      <div class="bar c"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

` but it didnt work. Not sure what I am doing wrong. I have tried other stuff but it isn't working. I have attached my code to this post. Please run code to understand. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add this code in css

```
 .phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 60px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
```

```css
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}

.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: grey;
  height: calc(100% - 65%);
  top: 10%;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar-phase-label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar.a {
  background-color: #ba55d3;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 25%;
}

.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar.b {
  background-color: #ff8c00;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 40%;
}

.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar.c {
  background-color: #81c784;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="phase-balancing-bar-graph-container">
  <div class="graph-wrapper">
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar-phase-label">A</div>
      <div class="bar a"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar-phase-label">B</div>
      <div class="bar b"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar-phase-label">C</div>
      <div class="bar c"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok I see what you did. That worked. However, the labels (A, B, C) cannot be fixed at the top. They need to be on top of the bar and rise with the bar

Comment: oh. I will make changes in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```css
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper{
  position: absolute;
  width: 55%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: grey;
  height: calc(100% - 65%);
  top: 10%;
  padding: 0 20px 0 20px
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 60px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar-phase-label{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar.a{
  background-color: #BA55D3;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 25%;
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar.b{
  background-color: #FF8C00;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 40%;
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar.c{
  background-color: #81C784;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="phase-balancing-bar-graph-container">
  <div class="graph-wrapper">
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar-phase-label">A</div>
      <div class="bar a"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar-phase-label">B</div>
      <div class="bar b"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar-phase-label">C</div>
      <div class="bar c"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

I used `flex` for elements. Also I removed `position: absolute; top: 10%;` and `position: relative` from `.graph-wrapper` and `.bar-container`. No need to them. So I used padding at `.graph-wrapper` for a distance with border-bottom:

```css
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: pink;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 20px;
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper{
  width: 55%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: grey;
  height: calc(100% - 65%);
  padding: 10px 20px;  /*here*/
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container{
  width: 15%; /*here*/
  display: flex; /*here*/
  flex-direction: column; /*here*/
  justify-content: flex-end; /*here*/
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar-phase-label{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height:30%; /*here*/
}

.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar.a{
  background-color: #BA55D3;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 25%;
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar.b{
  background-color: #FF8C00;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 40%;
}
.phase-balancing-bar-graph-container .graph-wrapper .bar-container .bar.c{
  background-color: #81C784;
  transition: 0.5s ease;
  height: 70%;
}
```

```html
<div class="phase-balancing-bar-graph-container">
  <div class="graph-wrapper">
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar-phase-label">A</div>
      <div class="bar a"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar-phase-label">B</div>
      <div class="bar b"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bar-container">
      <div class="bar-phase-label">C</div>
      <div class="bar c"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```